# Checking whether a response contains a list of values in Robot Framework?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I'm new to robot so apologies if this is a stupid question, but I'm looking for means to pass a list to the built in method should_contain:

```
def should_contain(self, item1, item2, msg=None, values=True):
    """Fails if `item1` does not contain `item2` one or more times.

    Works with strings, lists, and anything that supports Python's `in`
    keyword. See `Should Be Equal` for an explanation on how to override
    the default error message with `msg` and `values`.

    Examples:
    | Should Contain | ${output}    | PASS |
    | Should Contain | ${some_list} | value  |
    """
    msg = self._get_string_msg(item1, item2, msg, values, 'does not contain')
    asserts.fail_unless(item2 in item1, msg)
```

so first the simple method in a test case, I know this syntax is wrong but is it possible to do something similar to:

```
Should Contain    ${RESPONSE}    "hello","world",250
```

I tried using a list variable and passing it in, this seemed to work but on deeper investigation it seems to just compare an element count rather than the actual element values which was disappointing

To get around the problem I just did Should Contain on the values I cared about.  The problem is I'm repeating Should Contain with different data on several lines, which clearly isn't good practice.

```
Should Contain  ${RESPONSE}    "Hello"
Should Contain  ${RESPONSE}    "World"
Should Contain  ${RESPONSE}    250
```

Is anybody able to offer some guidance or an improved method of achieving what I'm trying to do?  I was considering creation of a new method to allow it into a custom library but I figured there has to be a more simple way.  To be clear I don't care about order of the items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should Contain keyword does not accept a list type variable as 2nd parameter. You can make a workaround by using a FOR loop to parse through list:

```
*** Variables ***
${Response}    "250 hello world foobar"

*** Test Cases ***
Stackoverflow
@{list} =   Create List   hello   world    250
:FOR    ${item}    in     @{list}
\       Should Contain    ${RESPONSE}    ${item}
```

Answer (score 4):

The collections library has what you want

```
Library  Collections
List Should Contain Sub List  ${list1}  ${list2}
```

Fails if not all of the elements in list2 are found in list1.

Comment: See http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#List%20Should%20Contain%20Sub%20List